# No error shown but insertion in database is unsuccessful

Tags: android

Below is the code to my database. When running it on my phone,no error is displayed but insertion unsuccessful is displayed.

My Register_Page.java is as follows:

```
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;


public class Register_Page extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText Name, Pass , Email, Gender,Phone,Dob,City;
    no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.myDbAdapter helper;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register__page);
        Name= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_name);
        Pass= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_pass);
        Email= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_email);
        Gender= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_gender);
        Phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_phone);
        Dob=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_dob);
        City=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_city);

        helper = new no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.myDbAdapter(this);
    }
    public void addUser(View view)
    {
        String t1 = Name.getText().toString();
        String t2 = Email.getText().toString();
        String t3 = Pass.getText().toString();
        String t4 = Gender.getText().toString();
        String t5 = Phone.getText().toString();
        String t6 = Dob.getText().toString();
        String t7 = City.getText().toString();
        if(t1.isEmpty() || t2.isEmpty()|| t3.isEmpty() || t4.isEmpty() || t5.isEmpty() || t6.isEmpty() || t7.isEmpty())
        {
            no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.Message.message(getApplicationContext(),"Enter Both Name and Password");
        }
        else
        {
            long id = helper.insertData(t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7);
            if(id<=0)
            {
                no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.Message.message(getApplicationContext(),"Insertion Unsuccessful");

            } else
            {
                no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.Message.message(getApplicationContext(),"Insertion Successful");

            }
        }
    }

    public void viewdata(View view)
    {
        String data = helper.getData();
        no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.Message.message(this,data);
    }

}
```

My myDBHelper.java is as follows:

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Message;



public class myDbAdapter {
    myDbHelper myhelper;
    public myDbAdapter(Context context)
    {
        myhelper = new myDbHelper(context);
    }

    public long insertData(String name, String email,String pass,String gender,String phone,String dob,String city)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase dbb = myhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(myDbHelper.NAME, name);
        contentValues.put(myDbHelper.MyPASSWORD, pass);
        contentValues.put(myDbHelper.EMAIlId, email);
        contentValues.put(myDbHelper.GENDER, gender);
        contentValues.put(myDbHelper.PHONE, phone);
        contentValues.put(myDbHelper.DOB, dob);
        contentValues.put(myDbHelper.CITY, city);
        long id = dbb.insert(myDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null , contentValues);
        return id;
    }

    public String getData()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = myhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        String[] columns = {myDbHelper.UID,myDbHelper.NAME,myDbHelper.MyPASSWORD};
        Cursor cursor =db.query(myDbHelper.TABLE_NAME,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
        StringBuffer buffer= new StringBuffer();
        while (cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            int cid =cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(myDbHelper.UID));
            String name =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(myDbHelper.NAME));
            String  password =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(myDbHelper.MyPASSWORD));
            buffer.append(cid+ "   " + name + "   " + password +" \n");
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }

    public  int delete(String uname)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = myhelper.getWritableDatabase();


        int count=db.delete(myDbHelper.TABLE_NAME ,myDbHelper.NAME +" =? " ,new String[] {uname});
        return  count;
    }

    public int updateName(String oldName , String newName)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = myhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(myDbHelper.NAME,newName);
        String[] whereArgs= {oldName};
        int count=db.update(myDbHelper.TABLE_NAME,contentValues, myDbHelper.NAME + "= ?",whereArgs );
        return count;
    }

    static class myDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDatabase";    // Database Name
        private static final String TABLE_NAME = "myTable";   // Table Name
        private static final int DATABASE_Version = 1;    // Database Version
        private static final String UID="_id";     // Column I (Primary Key)
        private static final String NAME = "Name";    //Column II
        private static final String MyPASSWORD= "Password";// Column III
        private static final String EMAIlId= "Email-Id";
        private static final String GENDER= "Gender";
        private static final String PHONE= "Phone no.";
        private static final String DOB= "Date-Of-Birth";
        private static final String CITY= "City";

        private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+
                " ("+UID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
                " NAME  TEXT NOT NULL,"+
                " EMAILId TEXT NOT NULL,"+
                " MyPASSWORD TEXT NOT NULL," +
                " GENDER TEXT NOT NULL,"+
                " PHONE INTEGER,"+
                " DOB INTEGER,"+
                " CITY TEXT NOT NULL)";
        private static final String DROP_TABLE ="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME;
        private Context context;

        public myDbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_Version);
            this.context=context;
        }

        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            try {
                db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.Message.message(context,""+e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            try {
                no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.Message.message(context,"OnUpgrade");
                db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
                onCreate(db);
            }catch (Exception e) {
                no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.Message.message(context,""+e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My activity_register_page.xml is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/register"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText_name"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.36"
            android:text="Register Here"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="#3333ff"
            android:textSize="28dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70sp"
            android:autoText="false"
            android:text="Name :"
            android:textColor="#3368ff"
            android:textColorLink="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100sp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter your name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="160sp"
            android:text="Email-id :"
            android:textColor="#3368ff"
            android:textColorLink="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="190sp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter Email-id"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_pass"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
            android:hint="Enter Password"
            android:text="Password"
            android:textColor="#3368ff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_pass"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_dob"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="450sp"
            android:text="Date of Birth :"
            android:textColor="#3368ff"
            android:textColorLink="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_dob"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="480dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Date of Birth"
            android:inputType="date" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_phone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="540sp"
            android:text="Phone No. :"
            android:textColor="#3368ff"
            android:textColorLink="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_phone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="570sp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter Phone No."
            android:inputType="phone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_city"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="630sp"
            android:text="City :"
            android:textColor="#3368ff"
            android:textColorLink="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_city"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="660sp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter your City"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_gender"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="340sp"
            android:text="Gender :"
            android:textColor="#3368ff"
            android:textColorLink="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_gender"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="370dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="M/F/Others"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_register"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="720dp"
            android:background="#3368ff"
            android:onClick="addUser"
            android:text="Register"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

What is the problem with the code?? 
Can anyone explain and help rectify the error??

Comment: You should read https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: compare id == -1 in if condition return by  helper.insertData(t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7); if data is not insert then it will return -1 other wise data insert into your database

Answer (score 0):

try this code replace with your code

```
if(id == -1)
        {
            no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.Message.message(getApplicationContext(),"Insertion Unsuccessful");

        } else
        {
            no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.Message.message(getApplicationContext(),"Insertion Successful");

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In db helper you are declaring constant fields for column names, and you use them in your insert methods. When you are creating db you should also use those values instead of hardcoding values.

So change this

```
 private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+
            " ("+UID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
            " NAME  TEXT NOT NULL,"+
            " EMAILId TEXT NOT NULL,"+
            " MyPASSWORD TEXT NOT NULL," +
            " GENDER TEXT NOT NULL,"+
            " PHONE INTEGER,"+
            " DOB INTEGER,"+
            " CITY TEXT NOT NULL)";
```

with declared constant fields

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDatabase";    // Database Name
        private static final String TABLE_NAME = "myTable";   // Table Name
        private static final int DATABASE_Version = 1;    // Database Version
        private static final String UID="_id";     // Column I (Primary Key)
        private static final String NAME = "Name";    //Column II
        private static final String MyPASSWORD= "Password";// Column III
        private static final String EMAIlId= "Email-Id";
        private static final String GENDER= "Gender";
        private static final String PHONE= "Phone no.";
        private static final String DOB= "Date-Of-Birth";
        private static final String CITY= "City";
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to do debug steps on `insertData`, also `cursor.close()` before

```
return buffer.toString();
```

Comment: Can u brief me about how to debug insertData ??

Comment: android debugging, break points on line and attach to debugger, for more info: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html